# Why use Primal-dual Methods for Linear Programs

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

We know we can solve an LP directly using KKT matrix method, even for QPs this works, for an example problem

$$
\min_{x_1,x_2} x_1^2 + x_2^2 \quad \textrm{s.t.}
$$
$$
x_1 + x_2 = 5
$$

KKT matrix is

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
Q & A^T \\ A & 0
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x \\ u
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-c \\ b
\end{array}\right] 
$$

then we can solve

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\cdot
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ u
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 0 \\ 5
\end{array}\right] 
$$

But I usually see in lectures on LPs primal-dual methods are used, for problems such as

$$
\min_x f(x) \quad \textrm{s.t.}
$$
$$
Ax = b
$$
$$
h_i(x) \le 0, \quad i=1,..,m
$$

Even if there were inequalities we know we can turn them into the form above. Then my question is why even bother with the primal-dual method when there is a method that works through a single linear algebra solve call? Is it done to lay some ground work for future cases when problems might not be convex, or differentiable etc?

Thanks,

Comment: An inequality constrained problem cannot be transformed to a purely equality constrained problem with free variables. Therefore you need something new.

Comment: Wait.. isn't this done regularly for LPs? https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/30210/30210_F07/presentations/converting.pdf  In fact I read somewhere "every solver will first convert a problem into the standard form".

Comment: In standard form you have non-negativity constraints, in addition to the equalities

Comment: ... which the KKT matrix method would not solve.. bcz it uses a simple matrix inverse after all, which puts no constraints on the variables solved.. Did I understand that right?

Comment: Right I forgot even after standardization we have  remaining inequality constraints, though "trivial", which are positivity of all variables. KKT matrix inverse wld not acct for that. Small stuff like this matters in Opt...:) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For which you need to give an example of the problem.

Your problem we can solve by C-S: $$x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac{1}{2}(1^2+1^2)(x_1^2+x_2^2)\geq\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)^2=\frac{25}{2}.$$
The equality occurs for $$(x_1,x_2)||(1,1),$$ which gives $x_1=x_2=\frac{5}{2},$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: Sure this prob can be solved algebrically as well; my point was equality constrained QPs can be solved using KKT matrices AFAIK, same for LPs. Then why use primal-dual methods (which are iterative) to solve such problems? For demonstration purposes?

Comment: @BBDynSys Your method not always works. In the general case it's impossible to use it.

Comment: @BBDynSys For example. Or we can get so horrible calculations that it''s better to use another methods.